Why do I get a 404 error when using Laravel with Render?
Helle everyone
I have some issue to reach my Laravel API hosted on Render. Everything works fine in localhost (http://localhost:8000/api/) but when I try with the Render url (https://myapi.onrender.com/api), I get an error 404. I used this tutorial to deploy my api and I'm using postman to make the requests.
The only thing I have in the log is

::1 - - [26/Sep/2024:21:07:46 +0000] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 404 485 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.42.0"

I'm using laravel 11 with php 8.3.
Does someone know how to fix this ? 
Thanks
Edit 1 : 
So I did some digging. Apparently the issue is when I'm adding something behind the Render url... This "https://my_url/" works but this "https://my_url/api" does not.
So I told my self "maybe the routes are not created" so I added this commad "php artisan route:list" and here is the output :

POST api/products ...... products.store › ProductController@store


GET|HEAD api/products ...... products.index › ProductController@index


GET|HEAD api ............................ generated::lnwA0mh8RHztYh4y

As you can see, the routes are created. So I think the the issue is comming from the "nginx-site.conf" file :
server {
  # Render provisions and terminates SSL
  listen 80;

  # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
  server_name _;

  root /var/www/html/public;
  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  # Disable sendfile as per https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/virtualbox.html
  sendfile off;

  # Add stdout logging
  error_log /dev/stdout info;
  access_log /dev/stdout;

  # block access to sensitive information about git
  location /.git {
    deny all;
    return 403;
  }

  add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
  add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

  charset utf-8;

  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

  error_page 404 /index.php;

  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|webp|tiff|ttf|svg)$ {
    expires 5d;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params+
  }

  # deny access to . files
  location ~ /\. {
    log_not_found off;
    deny all;+
  }

  location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    deny all;
  }
}

But I don't know where... Does someone sees what is wrong ?

Run the following commands to clear and cache the routes again:
php artisan route:clear php artisan route:cache

Where should I use those commands? I didn't see anywhere where I can write command in Render

@YohDono you have to do it in a Shell

@francisco thanks ! I tried the commands but same result
